# Node.js module for RDF store (persistent) and support for SPARQL HTTP Protocol?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rdf, sparql, rdfstore

I am looking for a Node.js module that will act as persistent RDF storage and also will have support for an SPARQL protocol (endpoint).

Actually, I have/will some RDF that I should publish as Linked Data and also to allow access to the RDF data through a SPARQL endpoint.

Any help is welcome! Thanks.

Cheers!

Comment: You may be interested in this question here - http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/3858/rdf-store-for-use-with-nodejs - though I don't think anyone was able to suggest a good one at the time but something may have been developed in the meantime

Answer (score 1):

[RDFStore-js](https://github.com/antoniogarrote/rdfstore-js) now supports persistence, using MongoDB as the backend, and the SPARQL protocol for HTTP access.

You can take a look at the 'Stand-alone SPARQL end-point' section of the README file for the details.

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search turned up this on Github - https://github.com/antoniogarrote/rdfstore-js

Looks like it will do exactly what you want

Comment: I came in contact with the author of rdfstore-js and there are 2 problems:
1. does not implement SPARQL HTTP Protocol,
2. Does not support persistent storage.

Comment: @Milan Hmm ok, but given that it has a Node.js build and Node.js is a HTTP server it should be a relatively simple to implement that part yourself surely?  And given that it supports SPARQL does it not support sending requests to remote endpoints i.e. could you not interact with persistent storage via SPARQL Query and Update?

Comment: @Milan Also I notice that the library has a module js-tree which provides *"in-memory and persistent tree data structures"* so it may be possible to modify the code yourself to make the storage persistent

Answer (score 0):

I'm bumping this thread since I was looking for similar solution and found something.

As of today, there is a set of 3 NodeJS modules filling the use case and still maintained:

- [quadstore](https://github.com/beautifulinteractions/node-quadstore) : implementation of a RDF store
- [quadstore-sparql](https://github.com/beautifulinteractions/node-quadstore-sparql) : the sparql engine to query the store
- [quadstore-http](https://github.com/beautifulinteractions/node-quadstore-http) : the HTTP server that expose endpoint

I just created a gist on github with a minimal usecase : https://gist.github.com/antoine-morvan/0b0505147771c492e25a90f88ca4ea40